# Show image in 4:5 ratio and fit inside container view in react native

Tags: css, image, react-native

I am not aware of the image ratio uploaded by user upfront but I need to display all images in 4:5 ratio i.e

```
image width=device window width size 
image height=(device window width size)*5/4
```

I used the above calculation for displaying my image inside container view  but the image is cropped. If I use resize mode, the image is distorted.

Code:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.fixedRatio} source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.uri }}/>
    </View>

    container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    fixedRatio: {
      marginLeft:-10,
      marginRight:-10,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      flex: 1,
      aspectRatio: 1,
      width: deviceWidth,
      height: deviceWidth*5/4
    },
```

**Edit 1:**

As per @marson answer, I changed the code like below

I set background color to differentiate image. Now the images are not get cropped. But doesn't fit inside the view

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'blue', aspectRatio:4/5, alignSelf:'center', width: '100%'}}>
   <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.uri }}/>
</View>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Could this work?

```
<View style={{
  width: '100%',
  aspectRatio={4.0/5.0}
}}>
  <Image
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
    }}
    resizeMode={'contain'}
    source={...}/>
</View>
```

Comment: No. Image is cropped.

Comment: @Inaccessible Is that your image is not in the aspect ration of 4:5, but you want to fit it inside a box of 4:5 as large as possible?

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't know the image ratio upfront but I need to display all images uploaded by user in 4:5 ratio

Comment: That's weird, with resize mode "contain" the image should fit in as large as possible, with "cover" then the image is cropped. There might be other codes affecting your result?

Comment: No. I didn't use any other css styling. Refer my code                                   
 <View style={{ width: '100%', aspectRatio:4.0/5.0}}>
          <Image resizeMode={'contain'} source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.uri }}/>
        </View>

Comment: You're not completely copying my code, the `<Image>` needs `width` and `height` to be `'100%'` too.

Comment: Please see my edited post. Now the images are not cropped!!. But doesn't fit inside the view

Comment: @Inaccessible Is the image provided fully displayed now? I mean, like the first image, is your image exactly looking like a headless woman? If it is fully displayed (or complete), then the image not occupying the `View` is very likely, since your image is not in the ratio of 4:5. If you want the image to completely cover the `View` you could use `resizeMode={'stretch'}` but the image would lose its aspect ratio.

Comment: In my case I set the background to gray so it won't look bad. Or you could set it to black like many apps do.

Comment: Thanks. In my case, I set backgroundcolor into white and set resizeMode={'cover'}. Now the image fully fit inside view

Comment: @Inaccessible Nice! But please note that cover mode would crop the image as it tends to fill in all the spaces.

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Cover mode crop the image. Currently I am planning to resize the image on server side.

Comment: @Inaccessible Great, then it's another level's problem, haha